# Fitnesse plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, fitnesse, acceptance-testing

I'm working with Fitnesse as an acceptance test tool.
I'm right the fixture in java.
And i'm looking for a good plugin for the eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one at `code.google.com` repos but its last updated 2011

URL: http://code.google.com/p/fitnesse-editor/

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternate url for the same; and its working!! All the other urls seems to be not in work.

```
http://fitnesse-editor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fiteditSite/
```

[image]